# How to extract part of excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to extract a part of an excel cells, but the starting chars is not always in the same position.

The rule is that I need to extract the text at the right of a determined char.

For example I need to extract the last part of email address (so after char @)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the email address is in `B1` you can use this -

```
=RIGHT(B1,(LEN(B1)-FIND("@",B1)))
```

What this does is take the number of characters in `B1` (`LEN`) and subtracts the position of the **@** character (`FIND`) - this gives you the number of characters to the right of the **@**. Now you can use the `Right` function to get those characters.

You can change it based on the location of your data.

- [Right KB](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RIGHT-RIGHTB-functions-240267ee-9afa-4639-a02b-f19e1786cf2f)
- [Len KB](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEN-LENB-functions-29236f94-cedc-429d-affd-b5e33d2c67cb)
- [Find KB](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628)

Comment: It isn't required, but for the sake of improvement and value to the community, can you explain what the formula does? Per the [help]: *Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.*

Comment: @Tyson it works but I have to modify with " ; " instead of " , " (maybe it is cause by my regional version)

Comment: That required substitution need does sound like it's caused by a different regional setting. @ale